# How does the RMI Instruction Operand Encoding of ROUNDSS work?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, machine-code, instruction-encoding

A few x86 instructions like [ROUNDSS](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/roundss) require this seemingly obscure instruction operand encoding, on which I can't find any documentation or definition in Intel's Software Developer's Manual.

How are the bits of this encoding used? I put `66 0f 3a 0b c0 0c` (`roundsd xmm0,xmm0,0xc` ) into a dissembler and varied the bits to gain a better understanding, but could only access half the XMM registers.

I'm also unclear on the meaning of

> 128-bit Legacy SSE version: The first source operand and the destination operand are the same.

as e. g. `66 0f 3a 0b c1 0c` is disassembled without warning/error to `roundsd xmm0,xmm1,0xc`.

Comment: In `roundsd xmm0,xmm1,0xc`, the high bytes to merge the result into are read from `xmm0`, and then the unchanged high half with the round result in the low half are written back to `xmm0`.  The VEX version would allow reading a different merge source.  Same as with other scalar one-input XMM instructions like `sqrtss` that are unfortunately designed with a false dependency on the destination, instead of zero-extending.

Comment: Understood, so reg1 != reg2 is valid, thanks!
Btw, also thanks for the additional tags!

Comment: With the legacy encoding, you need a REX prefix to access the other half of the registers (the new VEX prefix has those bits built in)

Comment: This is not really obscure.  RMI is also used for the three operand form of `imul` for example.  And that dates back to the 386.  It's just reg+r/m+imm.  I.e. RM but there's also an immediate.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this means the second-to-last byte encodes two operands, 3 bits for the first, 3 bits for the second ... and two bits for something else (mode?)?

Comment: @soc Correct.  This is called a *modr/m byte*.  It's the same as with any other instruction where the instruction encoding is given with a `/r` or `/0` to `/7` element.  Refer to the Intel Software Development Manual for how the modr/m and SIB bytes work.

Comment: @soc Is there anything missing with my answer?  If yes, please let me know so I can amend it with the bits you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Legacy Encoding

The encoding is as follows:

```
66 0F 3A 0A /r ib
```

The opcode is `0A` in the `0F 3A` opcode plane.  A mandatory `66` prefix must be supplied.  The opcode is followed by a modr/m byte (`/r`) encoding the first operand in the R field and the second operand in the R/M field.  The instruction is followed by an 8 bit immediate (`ib`) encoding the third operand.

Let's encode for example

```
roundss xmm8, [rdx+r9*8+64], 0xc
```

We have `xmm8` and `r9` as “upper” registers, so a REX.RX prefix `46` must be supplied to hold the extra bits.

The modr/m byte is `44` indicating an 8 bit displacement (mod = 01), presence of a SIB byte (r/m = 100), and `xmm8` as a reg operand (reg = 000, REX.R set).

The SIB byte is `CA` indicating `rdx` as the base (base = 010), `r9` as the index (index = 001, REX.X set) and a scale of 8 (scale = 11).

Then follows the displacement `40` (i.e. decimal 64).

Finally, we have the 8 bit immediate `0c`.

These bits are then assembled in the order legacy prefixes, REX prefix, opcode plane prefix, opcode, modr/m byte, SIB byte, displacement, immediate.  So the entire instruction comes out as

```
66 46 0F 3A 0A 44 CA 40 0C
|  |  |     |  |  |  |  \... immediate
|  |  |     |  |  |  \...... displacement
|  |  |     |  |  \......... SIB byte
|  |  |     |  \............ modr/m byte
|  |  |     \............... opcode
|  |  \..................... opcode plane prefix
|  \........................ REX prefix
\........................... mandatory prefix
```

### VEX Encoding

> 128-bit Legacy SSE version: The first source operand and the destination operand are the same.

The VEX encoded variant of the instruction `vroundss` has an additional source operand.  Instead of this operand, the legacy encoded version reads this source operand from the destination operand.

If we want to encode this instruction as the VEX-encoded variant

```
vroundss xmm8, xmm2, [rdx+r9*8+64], 0xc
```

instead, we start with a VEX prefix.  This prefix subsumes mandatory prefix, REX prefix, and opcode plane prefix into one 3 byte prefix.  This prefix has the form:

```
11000100 RXBmmmmm WvvvvLpp
R, X, B: complemented REX prefix bits
W: REX.W prefix bit (not complemented)
m: opcode plane (1: `0F`, 2: `0F 38`, 3: `0F 3A`)
L: vector length (0: 128 bit, 1: 256 bit)
p: mandatory prefix (0: none, 1: `66`, 2: `F3`, 3: `F2`)
v: complemented extra source register number
```

A shorter 2 byte VEX prefix

```
11000101 RvvvvLpp
```

can be used when REX.X, REX.B, and REX.W are clear and m = 00000.  This is not the case here.  The encoding is given as

```
VEX.LIG.66.0F3A.WIG 0A /r ib VROUNDSS xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/m32, imm8
```

indicating that the L and W fields are ignored, there is a mandatory `66` prefix and the opcode is `0A` in the `0F 3A` opcode plane, followed by modr/m operands and a byte immediate.  The first and third operands are encoded in the modr/m byte, the second operand is the additional operand encoded by the VEX prefix.

So we have for our instruction

```
R = 0, indicating presence of REX.R
X = 0, indicating presence of REX.X
B = 1, indicating absence  of REX.B
W = 0, indicating absence  of REX.W (ignored)
L = 0, indicating a 128 bit operand size (ignored)
m = 00010, indicating the 0F 3A opcode plane
p = 01, indicating a 66 mandatory prefix
v = 1101, indicating xmm2 as a first operand
```

Giving the VEX prefix `C4 22 69`.  The rest is identical to the legacy encoding, giving a full instruction

```
C4 23 69 0A 44 CA 40 0C
|        |  |  |  |  \... immediate
|        |  |  |  \...... displacement
|        |  |  \......... SIB byte
|        |  \............ modr/m byte
|        \............... opcode
\........................ VEX prefix
```